# Не грузится шрифт с google site

Tags: css, шрифты

Здравствуйте, нужен нестандартный шрифт на `Blogger`. Загрузил шрифт на `googlesite` - но проблема в том что шрифты работаю, только тогда, когда я нахожусь в этом аккаунте, а если выйти из него то шрифты не грузятся, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ссылку на сайт можно?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что Google Sites это не обычный хостинг где прямая ссылка на файл есть. Здесь есть, так называем, токен ключ и поэтому когда вы разлогиненны, он вам и не показывается.

Шрифт лучше загрузить на какой-то другой хостинг. Я для этого держу сайт на uCoz. Как вариант - Google Drive, Dropbox ибо там можно получить прямую ссылку на файл.

Answer (score -1):

Подгружайте шрифты с Google Fonts.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?